# Javascript failing to work on the internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some issues with this code appearing only on internet explorer version: IE11. This is a short version of the explanation. Got code console error:original message SCRIPT1002: Syntax error: and link pointing to : => value.

```
// Bind click events to toggle buttons and pass in slide flip value
                                next.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                    pushSlide(1);
                                });
                                prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
                                    pushSlide(-1);
                                });
```

I can provide additional information here.
http://scorpion3d.com/index.html#fotografija

This link will direct you to the issue. OK so below is the whole code if you will try it on other browsers, it's working just fine. Images are showing, no issues on the console etc.. but on internet explorer I cant see any images buttons working, and I don't know how to fix it.
full java script below:

```
// Flickr configurations
// Obfuscated API key var for demo
const _0x6e6e=["\x65\x66\x63\x38\x33\x64\x63\x63\x64\x37\x63\x31\x64\x30\x61\x65\x39\x33\x66\x34\x61\x61\x37\x61\x66\x62\x39\x37\x31\x66\x63\x65"];const apiKey=_0x6e6e[0]
// To personalize app, replace with your own API key
// const apiKey = '';
const album = '72157688964206172',
    albumOwner = '154845055@N05',
    flickrUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    method = '?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=',
    perPage = '100',
    formatCallback = '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1',
    contentContainer = document.getElementById('carouselContent'),
    oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Handle a response from the Flickr API
function reqListener () {
    const flickrPhotos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(flickrPhotos.photoset);
    // Parse response for album and owner information
    const ownerName = flickrPhotos.photoset.ownername,
        albumTitle = flickrPhotos.photoset.title,
        albumUrl = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/' + albumOwner + '/albums/' + album,
        albumOwnerUrl = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/' + albumOwner;
    // append response data to HTML DOM elements
    albumInfo.innerHTML = albumTitle;
    owner.innerHTML = ownerName;
    albumLink.href = albumUrl;
    albumOwnerLink.href = albumOwnerUrl;
    // Iterate through flickrPhotos in the response
    flickrPhotos.photoset.photo.forEach(function(foto) {
        // Generate the URL for individual photo based on template
        const url = 'https://farm' + foto.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + foto.server + '/' + foto.id + '_' + foto.secret + '.jpg';
        const photoTitle = foto.title;
        // Generate the necessary slide markup
        //   <span data-function="slide">
        //       <p>title</p>
        //       <img src="" />
        //   </span>
        const span = document.createElement('span'),
            img = document.createElement('img'),
            title = document.createElement('p');
        // append response data to generated HTML DOM elements
        img.src = url;
        img.alt = photoTitle;
        title.innerHTML = photoTitle;
        span.dataset.function = 'slide';
        span.appendChild(title);
        span.appendChild(img);
        // Now append the new slide to the slide container
        contentContainer.appendChild(span);
    });
    // Remote API request has been made and processed, initialize the carousel.
    flickrCarousel();
}
// API call to Flickr
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", flickrUrl + method + apiKey + '&photoset_id=' + album + '&user_id=' + albumOwner + '&per_page=' + perPage + formatCallback);
oReq.send();
// Carousel function
function flickrCarousel () {
    // set scoped variables
    const carouselBox = document.getElementById('carouselBox'),
        prev = carouselBox.querySelector('.prev'),
        next = carouselBox.querySelector('.next'),
        slides = carouselBox.querySelectorAll('[data-function=slide]'),
        deck = slides.length;
    let slide = 0,
        currentSlide = slides[0];
    // Find current slide of array and add selector
    currentSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
    // slider function
    function pushSlide(flip) {
        // Use value of array to find node and remove selector
        currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
        // Using value of current slide, add flip value to determine next slide value
        slide = slide + flip;
        // allows for full rotation of carousel; if 0 set value to -1 of array length
        if (flip === -1 && slide < 0) {
            slide = deck - 1;
        }
        // allows for full rotation of carousel; if max length of array, set to 0
        if (flip === 1 && !slides[slide]) {
            slide = 0;
        }
        // determine active slide and add selector
        currentSlide = slides[slide];
        currentSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
    }
    alert('11111111111111111111111111');
    // Bind click events to toggle buttons and pass in slide flip value
    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
        pushSlide(1);
    });
    prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
        pushSlide(-1);
    });
    // Bind keyboard events to slide triggers
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
            pushSlide(1);
        }
        if( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
            pushSlide(-1);
        }
    });
};
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: IE11 doesn't support that syntax.  Use a transpiler.

Comment: Hello, i believe it is not solution, sorry. Besides that it is syntax error i can see from the log.....
this is the output from transpiler:
[stdin]:2:21: error: unexpected indentation
         pushSlide(1);
                    ^

Comment: No; that is exactly what your problem is.  That error is from a linter; either fix it or reconfigure your linter.

Comment: You need an ES6 shim. ...and it's called Internet Exploder. :-)

Comment: Hello, sorry for argue but u was right, i've compiled with Niles "babel" compiler, now i can see images, of course handles (arrows ) for image switching missing but at least i can see image. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is written with ES6 syntax, E11 doesn't seem to support this JavaScript syntax. You will need to remove all `const`s and `let`s and  `=>`s. Likely you will need to remove much more if you do this by hand.

This can be automated by using a transpiler. My favorite is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: hello, bable compiler is a great tool i did not new.Thanks this solutions almost fixed all issues, only the switching arrows are missing, but i can see an image at least, and move forward to fix the arrows.